# 2 DELETE, only one working [POSTGRESQL]

Tags: php, postgresql, sql-delete

I'm literaly going crazy over this one.
So I have my gamePage.php file where I can see all the info about a single videogame.
The button delete invokes the following code

```
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $query="DELETE FROM shop.videogame WHERE IDVideogame='$id'";
        pg_query($conn, $query);
        $query="DELETE FROM shop.storage WHERE videogame='$id'";
        pg_query($conn,$query);
        echo 'Game deleted, click the "Go Back" button';            
     }
```

What actually happens is that only the second Delete works. The videogame is deleted from the storage table, but not from the videogame table. 
What's even stranger is that if I click a second time the button, the first DELETE finally works.

In other words one is supposed to click for 2 times the same button for no reason.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You should have error reporting turned on.

Comment: do you have integrity constraints in either table ?

Comment: Please, [confirm that this is not your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21798517/4903925) (case sensitive in unquotted SQL operation)... finally, add a vardump to the result of each operation an log it, then post on your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `shop.storage.videogame` is a ForeignKey to `shop.videogame.IDVideogame`.

If I have right, then switch delete statements.

```
$query="DELETE FROM shop.storage WHERE videogame='$id'";
pg_query($conn, $query);
$query="DELETE FROM shop.videogame WHERE IDVideogame='$id'";
pg_query($conn, $query);
```