# Adding Postgresql to an existing Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm following this guide,  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5.  I take out the 'sqlite3' gem and add 'pg', then run bundle install.  Then I change my config/database.yml file to look like the following

config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp5_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp5_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp5_production
  username: myapp5
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

For the next part, the guide gives me two choices and I have tried both.
Installing this gem 'rails_12factor' or add the following code to my 'config/environments/production.rb' file

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.public_file_server.enabled =     ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
  logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
  config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
end
```

Then if I run rake db:create followed by rake db:migrate it gives me errors so I run rake db:reset and that lets the migrations run through.  If I start up my site I get the error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "videos" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" ORDER BY "videos"."title" A...
                            ^
: SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" ORDER BY "videos"."title" ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2
Extracted source (around line #2):

<div class="container">
<% @videos.each do |x| %>
<p> <div class="child">  
  <video controls width="310" height="230" src="<%= x.file %>"></video>
    <p> <%= x.title %> </p>
```

When I take a look at my tables through ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables I see that videos exists.

["Videos", "ipaddresstrackers", "users", "votes", "schema_migrations", "ar_internal_metadata"]

Comment: Rename "Videos" to "videos". Postgresql is case sensitive for quoted names. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796446/postgres-case-sensitivity

Comment: can you share the migration file for "videos"?

Comment: It was a case sensitive problem, thank you!  If you would like to make this comment an answer I would gladly mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename "Videos" table to "videos".

> In PostgreSQL unquoted names are case-insensitive. Thus `SELECT * FROM videos` and `SELECT * FROM ViDeOs` are equivalent.
>
> However, quoted names are case-sensitive. `SELECT * FROM "videos"` is not equivalent to `SELECT * FROM "Videos"`.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798517/8098012).