# Is there a way to use ::regclass in a case sensitive way?

Tags: postgresql

I'm wondering if there is a way to use `::regclass` to convert a `string` to a `pg_class.oid` in a way that respects case sensitivity. Let me give an example. It's often handy to use `::regclass` to get the `oid` of a table, e.g. to list all columns of a table

```
SELECT * FROM pg_attribute WHERE attrelid = 'public.my_table'::regclass
```

However, `::regclass` implicitly converts the input to all lowercase before doing the search. (This is similar to how PGSQL will interpret table names in SQL commands, if you don't surround them with double quotes.) This means if your table is called `MY_table`, then you cannot use casting to `::regclass` to get its `oid`.

I know you can use other means, e.g. use `pg_class.relname` and `pg_class.relnamespace`. This question is specifically about using `::regclass`, because `::regclass` is more convenient (if I can find a way to make it work in a case sensitive way).

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM pg_attribute WHERE attreloid = '"public.my_table"'::regclass
```

but that includes the double-quotes in the name it searches.

Comment: Related: [Postgres Case Sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796446): *"When creating entities (tables, views, procedures, etc) in PostgreSQL, you should specify them either unquoted, or quoted-but-lowercased"*

Comment: Don't you mean `'"public"."my_table"'::regclass`? i.e. quote each component of the fully qualified name separately since the `.` is not part of the name itself.

Comment: oh. ::facepalm::. Putting the quotes so they don't surround the . fixes the second query. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason my second query didn't work is because the double quotes were around the . character. So here's how to do it.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_attribute WHERE attreloid = '"public"."my_table"'::regclass
```