# How to use WILDCARD using Dapper

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

How can I use LIKE wildcard in postgre DB using Dapper?
I have the following code:

```
string query = "SELECT name, index FROM article WHERE prefiks LIKE :prefix ;";
return conn.Query<myModel>(query , new { prefix = searchingValue }).ToArray();
```

Where searchingValue is a simple string. I tried few combinations which I already found:

```
return conn.Query<myModel>(query , new { prefix = "%" + searchingValue + "%" }).ToArray();
```

or

```
string query = "SELECT name, index FROM article WHERE prefix LIKE '%' || :prefix || '%'"
return conn.Query<myModel>(query , new { prefix = searchingValue }).ToArray();
```

But nothing works. I suppose that above solutions are fine for MS SQL but doesn't work under postgre;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work:

```
string query = "SELECT name, index FROM article WHERE prefiks LIKE :prefix ;";
searchingValue = "%" + searchingValue + "%";
return conn.Query<myModel>(query , new { prefix = searchingValue }).ToArray();
```

or simply, combine the concatenation in one line:

```
return conn.Query<myModel>(query , new { prefix = "%" + searchingValue + "%" }).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, you may use string concatenation in SQL itself:

```
string query = "SELECT name, index FROM article WHERE prefiks LIKE CONCAT('%', :prefix, '%') ;";
return conn.Query<myModel>(query , new { prefix = searchingValue }).ToArray();
```

Note: I am not postgresql expert; so you may need to tune some syntax; just in case.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21796446/5779732) question discusses about case sensitivity of postgresql; may be helpful.