# How to create a view in PostgreSQL containing ARRAY?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sql-view

I have a problem, I’m currently working with a Postgres database and what I want to do is to create a View from two tables. The problem is that one of the tables contains a column that is of the type “varchar ARRAY”. This column contains some sort of ID that I can use to get information from the second table.

I have the following:

Table 1: Person

- primary_name : varchar
- known_for_titles : varchar ARRAY  (array of t_const)  Table 2:

Table 2: Movie

- t_const : varchar
- primary_title : varchar

I want to create a view (actorView) that looks like this:
-primary_name : varchar
-famous_for : varchar ARRAY (array of titles)

I have this SQL that does not work properly, I manages to create the view but I can’t use the select statement on its own and I can’t ask a query on the view.

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW actorView AS
    SELECT p.primary_name,
           array_agg(t.primary_title) as famous_titles
FROM person p JOIN title t
                   ON t.t_const = any(p.known_for_titles)
    group by primary_name
```

When I try the select part of the SQL statement, it's just ends up searching in an endless loop and I have to terminate the query.

The same thing happens when I use the whole statement. It somehow manages to create the table but I can't search for anything.

Comment: See @TAM 's answer. You can run into problems in PostgreSQL if you don't name everything lowercase. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796446) for some details.

Answer (score 1):

I made the following modifications to your code:

- Changed the table names to lower case,
- made t_const a primary key, to be allowed to enter data in pgAdmin
- added a bigint id as primary key to person.

Also, I had to change the name title to movie to confirm to your table names. (Probably your table descriptions in the posting were not precise :-(  )

Then, the phrase

```
create or replace view actor_view as

SELECT p.primary_name,
           array_agg(t.primary_title) as famous_titles
FROM person p JOIN movie t
                   ON t.t_const = any(p.known_for_titles)
    group by primary_name
```

runs successfully for me.

The only substantial difference between your and my solution is the primary keys - the rest, I guess, were just typos in your posting. I don't know whether those pks make the difference, but it doesn't hurt to have them anyway.