# Weird error when trying to query from database

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

As the title suggests, I have no clue why this doesn't work. If someone can point out what I am doing wrong it would be sweet.

Here's the current table rows and cols:

Makes table:

```
 id |     make      
----+---------------
  1 | Acura
```

Models Table:

```
 id  |              model              | makesId 
-----+---------------------------------+---------
   1 | CL                              |       1
   2 | ILX                             |       1
   3 | Integra                         |       1
   4 | Legend                          |       1
   5 | MDX                             |       1
   6 | NSX                             |       1
   7 | RDX                             |       1
   8 | RL                              |       1
   9 | RLX                             |       1
```

I am trying to query from both tables using a simple line with the WHERE clause with the following query:

```
SELECT models.model, makes.make 
FROM models, makes 
WHERE models.makesId = makes.id;

funprojectdb=# SELECT models.model, makes.make FROM models, makes WHERE models.makesId = makes.id;

ERROR:  column models.makesid does not exist

LINE 1: ...models.model, makes.make FROM models, makes WHERE models.mak...
                                                         ^
```

HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "models.makesId".

The goal is to basically show me all of the models associated to the makes id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796446/postgres-case-sensitivity

Comment: Try: `...WHERE models."makesId" = makes.id`. You have a mixed case field name and to preserve case you need to quote it. FYI, try to avoid MixedCase and UPPERCASE identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys it works! I feel like an idiot asking this question.

Comment: Off-topic: the JOIN syntax became part of the SQL standard in 1992

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people that answered my question.

It was an issue with postgres case sensitivity which I completely forgot about.

I will be re-doing the database columns with proper field names.

Comment: You could rephrase this to make it a proper answer - i.e. demonstrate (perhaps also with a fiddle) what is happening when you use quoted identifiers - you could also point people at [this page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) - the bit about `Stick to using a-z, 0-9 and underscore for names and you never have to worry about quoting them`.