# Sum of points attributes inside intersection of two polygons

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a three different tables:

1. Polygons1

| Name1 | Geom |
| --- | --- |
| Name... | POLYGON.. |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

2. Polygons2

| Name2 | Geom |
| --- | --- |
| Name... | POLYGON.. |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

3. Points

| ID | Num | Geom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID... | 54 | POINT... |
| Cell 3 | 33 |  |

**I want to find where are polygons interesected and inside that area of intersection to sum points attribute - Num.**

I tried this query:

```
SELECT sum(Num) as total, Polygons1.Name1
from Points, 
     Polygons1, 
     Polygons2 
where ST_intersects(Polygons1.geom , Polygons2.geom)
GROUP BY Polygons1.Name1
```

This query returns some really big sum numbers that are not correct.
Please help.

Comment: You are not joining your tables correctly.

Comment: can you point me what is wrong and how to correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unless you double-quoted relation names back when you created them, they are actually lowercase. [Make sure you know how you name things.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21796446/5298879) Some tools auto-quote, some tools don't.
2. You specified how to pair up polygons. You didn't specify how to match points to those pairs of polygons - in this situation postgres assumes you want to link all points to each pair of polygons. You're likely seeing a repeated total sum of all `Points.Num` listed next to each `Polygons1.Name1` that found a matching geom in `Polygons2`. See [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iKuRoV8v).
3. You used implicit joins. It might be easier to [join your tables explicitly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html).

```sql
SELECT sum(p.Num) as total, 
       Polygons1.Name1
from      Polygons1 as plg1 
     join Polygons2 as plg2
     on ST_Intersects(plg1.geom, plg2.geom)
     join Points    as p
     on ST_Within(p.geom, ST_Intersection(plg1.geom, plg2.geom) )
GROUP BY Polygons1.Name1;
```

Make sure you're [clear on what you mean by *inside* and *intersection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM):

- If the polygons overlap sharing an area the shape of a smaller polygon and your point is in there, it's clear it's inside their intersection.
- If the polygons only share a side, their intersection is a line. Is a point on that line *inside* it, according to your criteria?
- If two squares only touch their corners, sharing a point, their intersection will be that point. If you have a point in that exact location, do you consider your point to be *inside* that other point, their intersection?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I followed the linked explanations step by step and now I see where my mistakes are and I can confirm that this query works.
And not to be left unanswered, the polygons ovelap sharing an area.