# SQL file can't be run as migration because of unclear syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following migration file which I want to execute using `go migrate` on a postgres database.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE user 
(
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 () PRIMARY KEY,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at TIMESTAMP without time zone
);
```

I get an error

> Details: pq: syntax error at or near "user"

I have tried different online SQL syntax validators but couldn't find the issue.

Questions:

- What's the syntax error?
- How can I better debug it myself next time?

Comment: User is [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Try other table name (maybe `USERS`?).

Comment: That was it. Thank you! Does it make a difference if the table name is uppercase or not in the migration file? Can you write a separate answer then I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: If you don't enclose table name in double quotes - it doesn't matter: dbms will automatically make it upper case.

Comment: @markalex: Is this answer no longer valid then ?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798517/724039  (and the comment: [but PostgreSQL folds them to lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796446/postgres-case-sensitivity/21798517#comment32988199_21798517) )

Comment: @Luuk, sorry wasn't aware of this postgres behavior, my bad.

Comment: @markalex I did not know tooo, but happened to read it 12 minutes ago 

Comment: Just don't use it period as per [Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html): *USER  reserved* and *Labeled “reserved” are those tokens that are not allowed as column or table names.*. While you can force it by double quoting the name, you will be fighting with that for the life of the table. Just avoid the hassle and pick another name.

Comment: Note that since Postgres 13, [gen_random_uuid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) is already built-in. No need to install an extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by the table name: User is [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Try other table name (maybe `USERS`?).