# PostgreSQL changes table name to lowercase

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am running this command with `sqlalchemy==1.4.31`.

```
with get_postgres_db() as postgres_session: 
    r = postgres_session.execute("SELECT * FROM shop.Clients;")
```

and it fails with

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "shop.clients" does not exist
```

but `shop.Clients` exists:

```
In [30]: with get_postgres_db() as postgres_session: 
    ...:     r = postgres_session.execute("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'shop';") 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  


In [31]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [31]: r.all()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[31]: 
[('DB', 'shop', 'Clients', 'BASE TABLE', None, None, None, None, None, 'YES', 'NO', None),
 ...]
```

and the table exists.

It appears that the request string will be filtered to lowercase the table name.
How can I disable this feature?

Initially I wanted to create a decorator that clears all tables with `DELETE FROM Clients;` and thats how I stumbled upon this.

Comment: Advice: Never user Uppercase in database object names, like the table name. Until you fixed that issue, use double quotes in every single query around the names where you did use Upper case: `SELECT * FROM shop."Clients";`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I am coming from MariaDB / MySQL and those quotes confuse me as they carry information. What do I need to read up on to understand the PSQL philosophy here?

Comment: ps: why not use uppercase database names?

Comment: because you have them escape the with double quotes, as postgres makes them else lower case, as you already noticed

Comment: Because you have to use the double quotes forever. It's really annoying to use, makes your code ugly, and within an hour you get tired of it. Just use lower case and you don't have these issues

Comment: Wondering who came up with this...  "We need to differentiate from the competition, lets add this feature"

Comment: Note that SQLAlchemy is not changing the name to lower case, PostgreSQL is. You would get the same error if you executed your query string from psql, DBeaver, or any other client. And, if you used SQLAlchemy Core to build the query then it would take care of quoting the mixed-case name for you.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796446/postgres-case-sensitivity

Comment: It was not * "We need to differentiate from the competition, lets add this feature"*. It was  the Postgres developers had/have an aversion to SHOUTING.

Comment: With shouting you mean 'SELECT * FROM Xyz;' ? So all caps for the SQL keywords?

Comment: select or SELECT, both work fine, no need for shouting. And it’s decision they made decades ago

Comment: I always considered ALLCAPS for SQL keywords a good way to read raw queries and have visiual indicators. But whatever, it is what it is... Thanks all!